# android ORMLite populate table on database create

Tags: android, database, ormlite

I'm using ORMLite in my android application. Is there a way when creating the database in the database helper to add some rows, or I must check in the main activity if there is already a database created and then create it and populate it if it doesn't exists.
What I want to achieve: When the application starts for the first time, add some data in the database (when creating the database file).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can certainly add as much as you like in the `onCreate` *or* `onUpgrade` methods.  Once you create the table, generate a DAO and do `dao.create(...);`.

If you look at the [`HelloAndroid` example application](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/ormlite/code/examples/android/HelloAndroid/src/com/example/helloandroid/DatabaseHelper.java), you can see that it does exactly that.

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db, ConnectionSource connectionSource) {
    TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, SimpleData.class);
    // here we try inserting data in the on-create as a test
    RuntimeExceptionDao<SimpleData, Integer> dao = getSimpleDataDao();
    // create some entries in the onCreate
    SimpleData simple = new SimpleData(System.currentTimeMillis());
    dao.create(simple);
}
```

Comment: This worked for me thanks. I have a question with this. Isn't there some other cleaner code way?